# video drivers corrupted

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics, display-adapter

I have a laptop that froze up the other morning after being on all night. I forced a power down after about 10-12 minutes of a white frozen screen and when I started up later the graphics drivers were corrupted and I'm only getting 1280 x whatever, which on a 16:9 screen looks awful. (I had a much higher resolution, 1920 x something, I think.

I have an ATI Mobility Radeo HD 4670 chipset.

Booting into Windows 7 Ultimate takes nearly 5 minutes (much longer than it used to) and seems to hang at various points.

If I boot up with logging mode it sometimes resets and reboots after starting Windows.

I ran one of the diagnostic startup options, and saw a message similar to 'invalid ACLS' and named two files in c:\windows\system32, but I didn't make a note of what the files were, nor can I find the diagnostic option to run to find out that message again.

When I went into the device manager and looked at the display adapter there was an exclamation mark against the ATI driver, and another display setting - and Intel something 4 adapter. I tried the 'update driver' option and it told me that I had the latest driver installed.

When I unintalled the driver - hoping that Windows 7 would recognise that I had a graphics display, but no driver for it, I get a timeout message saying that the driver couldn't be installed, but not a great diagnostic error message or further information on why.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT: I just noticed the hibernate option is not available now. I've reinstalled the drivers, but the machine still takes about 5 minutes to boot into Windows 7. It's also feeling generally sluggish.. I just timed it, and it took 7 minutes to get to a point I could open the Power Options system settings, and now it's hung when I click on the 'choose what to do when I close the lid option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My whole system went screwy, so I reinstalled the original drive, and reinstalled Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I want to advise you with some guidelines:

1) Download [Driver Sweeper](http://downloads.guru3d.com/download.php?det=745)

> Driver Sweeper is a fast tool to remove driver leftovers from your system. It's very important to remove your drivers on a proper way, because driver leftovers can cause problems like stability and startup problems. You can use it if you want to update/remove drivers from your system.

2) Go to your manufacturer site (ATI), and download the latest drivers for your graphics card
Choose the relevant drivers:

1. [ATI Catalyst™ Display Driver - For
   Windows 7 32BIT](https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/674/9206/0/www2.ati.com/drivers/mobile/catalyst_mobility_32-bit_util.exe)
2. [ATI Catalyst™ Display Driver - For
   Windows 7 64BIT](https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/674/9206/0/www2.ati.com/drivers/mobile/catalyst_mobility_64-bit_util.exe)

**Notes**: Make sure to restart the OS after cleaning the drivers from your system and before installing the new one.